# How to remove duplicates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have data looks like this:

```
Order No.  Name    Date   Unit Price  Freight
001        ABC     1-16    232         25
001        ABC     1-16    55          25
001        ABC     1-16    156         25
002        DEF     2-5     478         16
002        DEF     2-5     356         16
```

I am trying to let freight cost only show once in my table, the result would look like:

```
Order No.  Name    Date   Unit Price  Freight
001        ABC     1-16    232         25
001        ABC     1-16    55          0
001        ABC     1-16    156         0
002        DEF     2-5     478         16
002        DEF     2-5     356         0
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Current result:
Order No.  Name    Date   Unit Price  Freight
001        ABC     1-16    232         25
001        ABC     1-16    55          25
001        ABC     1-16    156         25
002        DEF     2-5     478         16
002        DEF     2-5     356         16

Comment: Looks like what you really need is to normalize your tables. You should have OrderHead and OrderDetail tables. The way you are doing this you are going to fight your denormalized structures forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a query to get what you want:

```
SELECT 
    order_no, name, theDate, unit_price, 
    case 
        when row_number() OVER (PARTITION by order_no ORDER BY order_no) = 1 then freight
        else 0 
    end as freight
from yourTable
```

This looks at all rows for each order number and provides the row number.  If it's row 1 of that order it uses the values of the freight column, otherwise it uses 0.

Note that I'm assuming that the freight value is the same across all rows for the same order number.

Comment: good answer... just one thing to note though (imo)... order by should be something other than order_no (i would do Date maybe) since everything within that partition will be the same anyways.

Comment: @samyi, I originally had date in the order by but decided to remove it since my assumption about the freight value being consistent across an order number made it redundant.

Comment: @MarkLeiber I'm sorry that I forgot to mention that my tables are actually join tables together, I don't think that partition will work if those are join tables.

Comment: It will still work. Do you want to edit your question to show the actual tables?

Comment: @MarkLeiber on my sql query, I also have lots of Case When statements.

Comment: @MarkLeiber on my sql query, I also have lots of Case When statements. I posted my sql statement as an answer to the question. Would you take a look at  it and see if there possible to apply partition function in my queries. Thanks!

Comment: Please delete the answer you added since it's not an answer.  You can meet me in chat to discuss this further: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79193/discuss-30537717